# entity framework and native sql access

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I asked this on EF forums and was suggested to try here too....

This question may be more relevant to Microsoft Product Development but anyone knowledgeable please reply too....

I am using EF 5, POCO, Code First, DbContext API from C# to access SQL Server and in future Oracle.
I find that I need to use native SQL to get access to underlying database features, performance and control. So I use context.Database.SqlQuery and context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand (with SqlParameters) a lot. I also need precise control over my Begin Transaction and Commit/Rollback/Set Transaction.

Are the above mentioned SQL Native facilities likely to be deprecated and removed in future EF versions?

Am I better off using ADO.Net and forget about using EF ?
Or perhaps ADO.Net will eventually get deprecated in favour of EF so I should stick to DbContext despite using mostly native SQL access?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a micro ORM such as dapper.

You can use this alongside EF or other gigantic ORMs or by itself. It lets you do straight SQL and map to strongly typed objects without a bunch of ceremony and it uses ADO.Net internally. ADO.Net isn't going away.

Something like this:

```
  var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select * from dogs");
```

More documentation here: https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net

Stackoverflow itself uses this for data access.